# c++ select return type between lists<string> and list<std::pair<string, string>>

Tags: c++, list, types, return

I want to make function like below:

```
list<string> or list<std::pair<string, string>> get(int a){
     list<string> a;
     list<std::pair<string, string>> b;

     if(a == 1)
        return a;
     else
        return b;

}
```

What is the best way to make function like above?

Comment: And why do you want to do such thing?

Comment: This feels like an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)

Comment: You could use a templated function with specialized versions.

Comment: You can return a `void *` to the list you want, but it feels like C: https://ideone.com/K33zrG example has memory leaks.

Comment: How are you going to use that function, if it existed?

Comment: Wild guess: you have some complex looping going on, where the inner part either generates a `string` or a `pair<string, string>`, depending on which version you want. `template<typename FUNC> list<std::invoke_result_t<FUNC(string)>> get(FUNC func) { /* complex looping */ result.push_back(func(value)); }`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't. C++ is *statically typed* which means you can't change the return type of a function at runtime.

But you can do something using *tuples* although it will be down to you to identify the active member:

```
std::tuple<list<string>, list<std::pair<string, string>>> x_y_problem() 
{
    return std::make_tuple/*ToDo populate as you need*/
}
```

and at the call site:

```
 list<string> x;
 list<std::pair<string, string>> y;
 std::tie(x, y) = x_y_problem();
```

Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/tuple/make_tuple

Comment: `variant<list<string>, list<std::pair<string, string>>>` also exists

Comment: Constructing a useless object every time upsets something deep inside of me.

Comment: @StoryTeller: But it did allow me to bury a pun or two. Does looking at these cheer you up? https://www.google.co.uk/search?q=puppies&rlz=1C1CHFX_en-GBGB544GB544&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwj0rc6l5KHWAhVCjFQKHWyaBD0Q_AUICigB&biw=1292&bih=843